# Is cis dipole moment is always greater than trans dipole moment?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

In trans compound the dipole moment always cancels each other!  Then how can it's dipole moment be greater than cis compound's dipole moment?

Comment: What _cis_ and _trans_ compounds are ou talking about?

Comment: I took the case of 2,3-dichloro 2-fluoro Ethene ---in this compound trans compound's dipole moment is higher than cis compound's dipole moment.  But why?

Comment: In this compound there are no _cis_ or _trans_. There are Z and E instead.

Comment: How is there 3 is an ethene?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No.**

The dipole moment of trans-cyclooctene ($\pu{0.82 D}$) is greater than *cis*-cyclooctene ($\pu{0.43 D}$). 
See [On the Molecular Geometry of trans-Cycloöctene](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01541a044), *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1958,** *80* (8), 1953–1955.

> Blomquist, Burge and Sucsy<sup>2</sup> have called attention to the fact that while with the cyclodecenes, the cis isomer has the higher density and index of
>   refraction as is typical in acyclic systems, with the cyclooctenes, as first noted by Ziegler and Wilms,<sup>3</sup> the reverse is true. From these refractive indices, by application of van Arkel’s dipole rule,<sup>4</sup> the prediction could be made that the trans-cyclooctene would have a higher dipole moment than the cis.
>
> [...]
>
> The dipole moments of the cis and trans isomers of cyclodecene were previously determined,<sup>4</sup> and were found to be normal. The conclusion, drawn from the dipole rule, that the trans-cyclooctene would have a higher dipole moment than the cis represents a situation without analogy.
>
> [...]
>
> The cis isomer was found to have $\mu_{cis} = \pu{0.43 \pm 0.06 D}$ which may be compared with the value found for *cis*-cyclodecene of $\pu{0.44 D}$.<sup>4</sup> The trans isomer was found to have a dipole moment of $\pu{0.82 \pm  0.03 D}$, compared with the value zero found for trans-cyclodecene.<sup>4</sup>

([Van Arkel's rule](https://books.google.com/books?id=AeN0G0H_61UC&q=%22The%20isomer%20with%20the%20higher%20dipole%20moment%20possesses%20the%20higher%20boiling%20point%22&dq=%22The%20isomer%20with%20the%20higher%20dipole%20moment%20possesses%20the%20higher%20boiling%20point%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjud653JDXAhWB2SYKHad3BrMQ6AEIJjAA) is: The isomer with the higher dipole moment possesses the higher boiling point, refractive index, and density.)

Comment: This is a very good example that challenges assumptions nicely.

Comment: "*On the Molecular Geometry of trans-Cycloöctene*" Nice o-umlaut you have there ;-) Also, have an upvote!

Comment: @paracetamol I was surprised to see the umlaut.  They use it throughout the article.

Comment: For general interest, the umlaut here essentially serves as a pronunciation guide---it's a somewhat antiquated way of distinguishing the diphthong 'oo' from two (separate) vowels next to each other 'o' + 'o', and you also see it in words like preëxistence, etc.

Comment: And in this context it shouldn’t be called *umlaut* but *trema*

Comment: @Jan not "trema", but "diaeresis" https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2012/04/we-resist-further-cooperation-cooperation/328832/ and also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66126/what-is-the-standard-rule-for-using-or-not-using-hyphen-and-diaeresis-on-the-wor

Comment: @DavePhD *trema* and *diaeresis* are both correct, the former is more descriptive of the shape the latter of the purpose in this case. Calling the German umlaut *diaeresis* is about as wrong as using *umlaut* here but both can be called *trema*.

Comment: @Jan fair enough